# A simple bit-math question on register bit manipulation

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, avr

I read in a tutorial such descriptions:

```
DDRD |= (1 << DDD0);        // sets bit DDD0 to 1 within register DDRD

PORTD |= (1 << PORTD0);     // turn on PD0
```

I can understand step by step the following example:

```
SREG |= (1 << 7);
```

Above means take 1 = 00000001

Shift it to left 7 digits so it becomes 10000000

Now expression becomes SREG | 10000000

So far so good but how about again the following:

```
DDRD |= (1 << DDD0);
```

How can we analyse it step by step? If I take DDD0 as zero then 1 becomes again 1 as 00000001 and expression becomes DDRD | 00000001.

Is DDD0 simply the number 0 here?

Comment: Isn't '||' OR operator in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you are using an Atmel AVR with `avr-libc` based on the register names. In which case if you refer to the `<libc>\include\avr\` directory, you will find files named after the processor. For example if you take the ATMega328p, there is a file called `iom328p.h`. Inside it we find a whole lot of things like:

```
#define DDRD _SFR_IO8(0x0A)
#define DDD0 0
#define DDD1 1
#define DDD2 2
```

Notice how DDRD is nothing but a special address for the DDRD register - imagine having to create a pointer to that register, having to look up it's address each time. It's much easier to #define it to a readable name.

Consider you want to write to the third bit in the `DDRD` register. You could do any of the following:

```
DDRD |= 1<<2;
DDRD |= 4
DDRD |= 1<<DDD2;
```

You will notice how `DDD2` is simply #defined as the number 2, so it is **identical** to the other lines. It is however much more readable - especially if you want to refer to the datasheet which uses the same names for bits.

You might wonder - ah but I'll never ever want to look up that bit as I know it is 2. Well consider another example. Lets take the timers. We have for example:

```
#define TCCR0B _SFR_IO8(0x25)
#define CS00 0
#define CS01 1
#define CS02 2
#define WGM02 3
#define FOC0B 6
#define FOC0A 7
```

Now lets say we want to set the WGM02 bit to be a 1. We could do either of:

```
TCCR0B |= 1 << 3;
TCCR0B |= 8;
```

But those are very unreadable - ridiculously so. Who know what 1 << 3 is in the register - we'd have to look it up in the datasheet. On the other hand:

```
TCCR0B |= 1 << WGM02;
```

is immediately obvious which bit it is setting.

Additionally there is an element of portability here. Many of the AVRs have the same timer module but have bits in different places - WGM02 might be in bit 1 in another AVR for example.

If you moved to a different device later on, you would have to go through every random magic number, look up in the old datasheet what bit it corresponds to, match that with the new datasheet, and change the constant. Whereas if you use the #define, you know what bit it is without looking in the old datasheet, and you may not have to change it at all because the new #define will take care of it.

---

**TL;DR;** You are massively overthinking things. It is done purely for neatness and to make things easier to follow not harder.

Comment: great explanation with a very nice example, now clear. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`DDD0` and `PORTD0` will be #defined macros in one of the header files.

So say DDD0 if the first bit in the DDRD register then somewhere in a header there will be a line `#define DDD0 0`, if it's the second bit in the register that #define will be 1 rather than 0 etc...

Once that header file is written you don't need to know which bit in the register DDD0 happens to be, you just need to known that `1<<DDD0` will get you to the correct bit.

Comment: If DDD0 is defined as zero and the expression is **DDRD |= (1 << DDD0);**, isnt that the same with DDRD |= (1 << 0)? I still dont get the use of things like DDD0 instead of numbers. What is the reason of using DDD0 here?

Comment: Your code gets to say "DDD0" in a way that is consistent with all other bit assignments, which is a hell of a lot more readable than "0" which requires something like:

DDRD |= 1; // Set DDD0 bit

Comment: Or another way, you're getting hung up on something that is done purely for readability and consistency.

Comment: Yes it's the same. The difference is it avoids you looking up in the manual which value to use. It's also less error prone and easier to debug, say you had a register with 32 1 bit flags in it. What would be more likely to happen and harder to spot, if someone has entered 23 instead of 22 or if they had typed in the wrong flag name? Generally magic numbers in the code are a bad idea because they make maintaining and debugging the code harder.

Comment: @Andrew Why would one look up the manual for DDD0? Doesnt that always mean the bit number zero? Im confused is DDD0 the bit or the number stored in that bit?

Comment: DDD0 is in uppercase, which is the convention for a constant, which means it's probably the position of the bit line. The pattern port |= (1 << shift) confirms that. You'll get to recognise these patterns with experience. In Hungarian notation, it might be called BIT_POS_DDD0, which is longer. It certainly seems redundant I know calling the constant  DDD0, but later on, you will find libraries, or write your own, that use LED_OUT or SELF_DESTRUCT_INITIATE in a similar way, and there it's not redundant. When the hardware changes, the constants can change, without change to your code, FTW!

Comment: @doncarlos From "iom328p.h" (or equivalent for your processor) in the avr-libc files: `#define DDD3    3
#define DDD2    2
#define DDD1    1
#define DDD0    0
etc.`. You are massively overthinking things.

Comment: DDD0 is the bit location of the DDD0 signal within the register. You've not given any links, part information or context but I'm assuming DDRD is an ATMega CPUs DataDirectionRegister for port D.  In that situation it is indeed true that DDD0 is indeed 0 and DDD1 is 1 etc...  However that is not always the case e.g. WGM02 sets the wave form generation mode in a timer register for those parts. It's bit 3 of the register not bit 2. FOC0A and FOC0B are bits 7 and 6. Do you really want to have to memorize that or constantly look it up to check the code is correct or is it easier to use the names?

Comment: Is DDD0 bit location or a number? location and number they are different things. there starts my confusion. if it is a number i dont still see any use of using DDD0 in bit manipulation and here it means we use DDD0 instead of zero which doenst make sense. 1<<DDD0 like operation after << there must be a number and means we are shifting 00000001 to left DDD0 times in this case zero times. I still dont get any use. But now u are saying it is a location.

Comment: Locations are numbers. A memory address is a number, a bit location within a register is a number. We are talking about computers here, everything is a number. It is the location of the DDD0 bit within the register. Which is going to be a number between 0 and 7 for an 8 bit CPU or 0 and 31 for a 32 bit CPU.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you have mistaken the `|` operator and the `||` operator.

By the looks of the named defines there you are programming an AVR chip?

I am guessing `DDRD` and `SREG` are registers. The reason why programmers use named defined constants is because it puts readibility and **meaning** into the code rather than a bunch of magic numbers. You don't really care what the numbers are but you do care what they mean and what their function is. Giving them a name helps with this.

```
DDRD |= (1<<DDD0); //is the same as
DDRD = DDRD | (1<<DDD0); 
// so take the current value of DDRD and do a OR operation on each corresponding bit
/* 
   if we say that for example DDRD is currently 0b10100010
   and DDD0 is 0 then (1<<DDD0) --> 0b00000001
   then we do a BITWISE OR
   --> 10100010
   OR  00000001 
     = 10100011
*/
```

I hope that makes some kind of sense but to reiterate each bit of each variable gets OR'ed together.

Comment: Im only focusing on the part: **1<<DDD0**.  What is hard to read here instead of writing   **DDRD |= (1 << DDD0);** to write just    DDRD |= 1; ??  DDRD |= 1 is very meaningful here. I dont get what makes DDD0 use so special here

Comment: Yes and I'm explaining why its done this way and what a bitwise OR is as opposed to a logical OR. If you thinks it harder to read thats your opinion but professionals always use defined names that mean something. Generally magic numbers are not accepted practice.

Comment: I'll tell you what. You write the code the way you want and let us know how well that works out for you once you get onto something more complex than setting a couple of port pins. The rest of use will do it the way we've described because we know from experience that it makes life a lot easier in the long run.